# Spell which causes grapple

Tags: spells, grapple, pathfinder-2e

Let me start by pointing out that I'm new to Pathfinder. I've played some Dnd and now our DM is migrating our campaing to PF2e.

I'm planning to build a new character, some necromancer of sorts, and I would very much like for it to have a specific spell.

I'm trying to find a spell (up to lvl 6) which grapples the target. I'm aware of the [Strangling Hair](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strangling-hair/) lvl 3 spell, and it is quite similar to what I want, but I wanted something that had an area of effect instead of just targeting one creature. My goal is to have something to lock several weak foes into place (slow them down or prevent them from moving altogether), so I wouldn't mind if it is ineffective against strong enemies.

If AoE is not possible, then I would like at least something stronger than Strangling Hair in terms of damage. I also would like to depict the spell as skelleton arms sprouting from the ground and holding the enemies into place, so it is a plus if the spell is somehow connected to this.

As @HeyICanChan pointed out, Strangling Hair is a *Pathfinder* spell, and not  a *Pathfinder 2e* one. This wouldn't be a deal-breaker, since our GM is pretty flexible, but I'd rather have something actually from *Pathfinder 2e*.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "lock down" targets? Do you want to immobilize them? Disrupt actions?

Comment: Made it more clear on the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Black Tentacles](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=23) is the staple area-effect grapple spell.** It is a 5th level spell with a 120-foot range that creates a 20-foot radius area that attempts grabs on any targets in the area at the time of the spellcasting and any that end their turn in the area.

There are also other spells that can immobilize and disrupt actions.

- The [Tanglefoot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=330) cantrip can slow movement and immobilize on a critical hit.
- [Entangle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=103) creates difficult terrain and can reduce speeds or immobilize on failed saves.
- [Entangling Creepers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=331) creates a large area of difficult terrain and can pull creatures into it each round to immobilize them on a successful spell attack.
- [Slow](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=289) or any other spell that causes the slowed condition is very effective at shutting down an enemy because it takes away actions.
- Any spell with the [incapacitation trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=93) is worth looking at. Spells with this trait usually can completely cripple a target on a failed save or critically failed save.

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of that spell from 3.5 and I wanted to do some research but you already found it! And other options as well! Good job! And since the DM is flexible the visual effect could be modified and the stats/effect be the same.

Comment: I know it's not directly related, but it might be worth including "lower level targets" in the incapacitation trait bullet, as they're unlikely to do more than inconvenience targets higher than your level. Or at least mention to Heighten them so they're effective at your level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Those are very interesting options :)